# Cannot send audio recorded on expo app to Speech To Text Azure API

Tags: azure, react-native, rest, mobile, expo

I'm trying to send a local audio recorded using expo-av to Speech-To-Text Microsoft Azure API but is not working.

This is my method to send the request to Azure.

```
const sendToAzure = async () => {
    const url = "https://brazilsouth.stt.speech.microsoft.com/speech/recognition/conversation/cognitiveservices/v1?language=pt-BR"
    const key = 'my-api-key';
    try {
        const uri = recording.getURI();
        const response = await FileSystem.uploadAsync(url, uri, {
            httpMethod: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': key,
            },
            uploadType: FileSystem.FileSystemUploadType.BINARY_CONTENT,
        });
        console.log('Response:', JSON.parse(response.body));
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}
```

The 'recording' was saved in a state before I start the audio record and used in this method to return the uri from the last saved audio. This is working fine, I can view and reproduce the audio by this uri.
But after sending this request, the Azure API returns me a code 200 (OK), but always with the result as a empty string "", like the audio was sent but has no content.

Already tried send with axios instead of updloadAsync from expo but not working too.
I think the problem is on the method I'm send the audio, don't know if the binary content is correct because already tried multiple ways and nothing...

Comment: The Speech service provides only speech to text and text to speech capabilities with a Speech resource. You can transcribe speech to text with high accuracy, produce natural-sounding text to speech voices, translate spoken audio, and use speaker recognition during conversations.

Comment: To store data we have different types for `File storage: Azure Storage blobs
Azure Data Lake and Storage Gen1`  ,`NoSQL databases: Azure Cosmos DB ,HBase on HDInsight`, `Analytical databases: Azure Data Explorer`                                       [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/data-guide/technology-choices/data-storage)

Comment: @Sampath Hi, I don't wanna save my audio on Azure cloud, just wanna send my audio that was saved on my local phone to Azure Speech to text API, just to get the transcription in text for the content on the audio. The problem were that I send my saved audio but Azure always returns me as a empty string ""

Answer (score 0):

The following simple React code uses Expo and Azure Speech to perform Speech-to-Text:

- This code allows users to select an audio file, and then it uses the Speech SDK to recognize speech from that audio file.
- Install the necessary npm packages for your React application.

```
npm install react react-native
npm install expo-av expo-document-picker
npm install microsoft-cognitiveservices-speech-sdk
```

- Replace placeholders (`YOUR_AZURE_SPEECH_KEY`  and  `YOUR_AZURE_REGION`) with your actual Azure Speech API key and region.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Text, View, Pressable, ActivityIndicator, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { Audio } from 'expo-av';
import * as sdk from 'microsoft-cognitiveservices-speech-sdk';
import * as DocumentPicker from 'expo-document-picker';

const SpeechRecognition = () => {
  const [recognizedText, setRecognizedText] = useState('');
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('');
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const recognizeSpeech = async (audioFile) => {
    try {
      const { sound } = await Audio.Sound.createAsync(audioFile);

      const audioConfig = sdk.AudioConfig.fromStreamInput(
        sound,
        16000, // Sample rate (adjust as needed)
        sdk.AudioStreamFormat.getWaveFormatPCM(16, 1)
      );

      const speechRecognizer = new sdk.SpeechRecognizer(speechConfig, audioConfig);

      speechRecognizer.recognizeOnceAsync((result) => {
        setLoading(false); // Stop the loading indicator
        switch (result.reason) {
          case sdk.ResultReason.RecognizedSpeech:
            const recognizedText = result.text;
            console.log(`RECOGNIZED: Text=${recognizedText}`);
            setRecognizedText(recognizedText);
            setMessage('Speech recognized successfully!');
            break;
          case sdk.ResultReason.NoMatch:
            console.log('NOMATCH: Speech could not be recognized.');
            setMessage('Speech could not be recognized.');
            break;
          case sdk.ResultReason.Canceled:
            const cancellation = sdk.CancellationDetails.fromResult(result);
            console.log(`CANCELED: Reason=${cancellation.reason}`);

            if (cancellation.reason === sdk.CancellationReason.Error) {
              console.log(`CANCELED: ErrorCode=${cancellation.ErrorCode}`);
              console.log(`CANCELED: ErrorDetails=${cancellation.errorDetails}`);
              console.log('CANCELED: Did you set the speech resource key and region values?');
              setMessage('Speech recognition canceled. Please check your settings.');
            }
            break;
        }
        speechRecognizer.close();
      });

      await sound.playAsync(); // Start playing the audio
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error:', error);
      setLoading(false); // Stop the loading indicator
      setMessage('Error processing the audio file. Please try again.');
    }
  };

  const pickDocument = async () => {
    try {
      const result = await DocumentPicker.getDocumentAsync({
        type: 'audio/*',
        copyToCacheDirectory: false,
      });

      if (result.type === 'success') {
        console.log('File picked:', result.uri);
        setLoading(true); // Start the loading indicator
        recognizeSpeech(result.uri);
      } else if (result.type === 'cancel') {
        console.log('Document picking canceled by the user');
        setMessage('Document picking canceled.');
      } else {
        console.log('Document picking failed');
        setMessage('Document picking failed. Please try again.');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error picking document:', error);
      setMessage('Error picking the document. Please try again.');
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const speechConfig = sdk.SpeechConfig.fromSubscription(
      'AzureSpeechKEY ',
      'AzureSpeechRegion'
    );
    speechConfig.speechRecognitionLanguage = 'en-US';
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.title}>Speech Recognition in React Native</Text>
      <Pressable style={styles.button} onPress={pickDocument} disabled={loading}>
        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Select .wav File</Text>
      </Pressable>
      {loading && <ActivityIndicator size="small" color="#3498db" />}
      {message !== '' && <Text style={styles.message}>{message}</Text>}
      <Text style={styles.result}>Recognized Text: {recognizedText}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    marginBottom: 20,
  },
  button: {
    backgroundColor: '#3498db',
    padding: 10,
    borderRadius: 5,
    marginBottom: 20,
  },
  buttonText: {
    color: 'white',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
  message: {
    color: 'red',
    marginBottom: 10,
  },
  result: {
    marginTop: 10,
  },
});

export default SpeechRecognition;
```

**local:**

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, but is still not working on my project. However I can explain more details about. The real problem is on the audio sent on the request to Azure. I can do the request to Azure with Axios for example, but the audio binary data that I'm sending on the request is not beeing recognized by Azure Speech to Text API.

Comment: Im trying to read the file using expofilesystem as a base64 because cant read as binary, after this im transforming into a buffer using node Buffer.from(base64, 'base64') and sending to Azure in an Axios request, the request returns 200 OK but always with the Display Recognition Text as a empty string ""

Comment: the real problem is on the expo read file and send the result of this method to azure, because I can read only on base64 and transforming to binary using node buffer is not working

Comment: Instead of using `expo-av` and `FileSystem.uploadAsync`, try using Axios for the entire request

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue as you, and I discovered that the default output format from `expo-av` is `.m4a` (with no setting to record directly to `.wav` as far as I know). However, the Azure API only supports `.wav`. Therefore, you need to convert the audio file from `.m4a` to `.wav` format (I use `ffmpeg-kit-react-native`), and now it works.